# python logging and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm adding logging to a time critical task running on resource-constrained hardware (Raspberry Pi).

I read about the QueueListener/QueueHandler in:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block

and I'm trying to understand how it really works and what's happening under the hood, in order to estimate what the impact would be.
So I wrote a test program (here at the bottom) that logs 500000 lines and then waits for the listener to terminate. I ran it on a PC:

```
$ python3 logtest.py 0
PID= 5974
[  0.000] Logging like crazy 500000 times with que = queue.Queue
[ 18.038] Done logging, waiting for completion
[ 37.824] Test finished
---
```

Here's the output while it's logging (within the first 18 seconds):

```
$ ps um -L 5974
USER        PID    LWP %CPU NLWP %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
iurly      5974      - 96.3    2  2.1 264232 170892 pts/2   -    15:30    0:07 python3 logtest.py 0
iurly         -   5974 72.8    -    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:30   0:05 -
iurly         -   5975 23.3    -    -      -     - -        Sl+  15:30   0:01 -
```

So the main thread is taking most of the CPU while the background thread is writing to disk, and that's reasonable.
However, as soon as it starts waiting for the logger to terminate, I get something like this:

```
$ ps um -L 5974
USER        PID    LWP %CPU NLWP %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
iurly      5974      -  100    2  3.9 406724 313588 pts/2   -    15:30   0:31 python3 logtest.py 0
iurly         -   5974 45.2    -    -      -     - -        Sl+  15:30   0:14 -
iurly         -   5975 54.8    -    -      -     - -        Rl+  15:30   0:17 -
```

Why is the main thread taking up so much CPU? What is it really doing?
I believe at this point listener.stop() should only be waiting for the helper thread to terminate. I imagine that would be implemented by waiting on a semaphore or something (i.e. iowait i.e. 0% CPU), but evidence shows this is not the case. What am I missing here?
Thank you!

Here's the test code:

```
RANGE=500000
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import time
import gc
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  testlist = [int(q) for q in sys.argv[1:]]
else:
  print ("no test list given, defaulting to 0 1 0 1")
  testlist = [0, 1, 0, 1]

print("PID=", os.getpid())
for i, qtype in enumerate(testlist):
  handlers = []
  if qtype == 0:
    que = queue.Queue(-1)
    qstring = "queue.Queue"
  else:
    que = mp.Queue(-1)
    qstring = "mp.Queue"
  handlers.append(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("test%d.log" % (i), maxBytes=100000, backupCount=5))
  #handlers.append(logging.lastResort)

  listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(que, *handlers)
  formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(threadName)s: %(message)s')
  for handler in handlers:
      handler.setFormatter(formatter)
  listener.start()

  queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(que)
  logger = logging.getLogger()
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  logger.addHandler(queue_handler)
  start = time.time()

  print("[%7.03f] Logging like crazy %d times with que = %s" % (time.time()-start, RANGE, qstring))
  for i in range(0,RANGE):
    logger.info("AAAAAA")
    if i % 2000 == 0:
      print(i, "/", RANGE, end='\r')


  print("[%7.03f] Done logging, waiting for completion" % (time.time() - start))
  listener.stop()
  print("[%7.03f] Test finished" % (time.time() - start))
  gc.collect()
  print("---")
```

Comment: When in doubt, `cProfile`. We seem to spend that time in `threading.Thread._wait_for_tstate_lock()` I wonder if it's some sort of busy wait?